# react.js change input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, onchange

I would like to change the values with javascript/jquery but when I hit submit, the old initial values are used and not my new ones.

I cannot change the react code, I can only change the values with javascript/jquery as shown below.

```
var value = "randomIntValue";
$("input[data-reactid='.0.2.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.0.3.0.3.0.0']").val(value).change();
```

The above code doesn't work!

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're not able to touch the react code? I'm sure there is an easy solution to create the desired output in react without using jQuery

Comment: It's not my own code and I must automate some processes, there are standart values inside the input fields, and I need to change them

Comment: Why are you using `change()`?

Comment: To trigger the event. I read some reactjs docs and saw that it's implemented like onchange(); but correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not familiar with reactjs

Comment: First I click an element on a page with jquery, then wait 2s and the set the values. This is successful, I see the new values. But then when I hit submit the values switch back to the defaultvalues and they are also submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather from the comments above, the problem you're having is that you're trying to change a React-controlled component through jQuery.

This is not possible because you cannot update the React state from the view directly. When you run your jQuery code, the changes are only temporarily applied to the DOM, but React does not know about this. As such, when React needs to re-render the view the old values in the DOM will be overwritten.

Also, accessing the component via the `data-reactid` is a bad approach because the value is likely to change if any changes are made the React virtual-DOM.

Using React and jQuery is usually a bad idea when trying to apply DOM changes. If you cannot access/change any React code, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: thank you, it helped me a lot to understand why it's not working. But when I focus the input field and type something in, then it's actually working ... isn't it possible to emulate this by jquery ... I'm thinking of focus(). No it's not my homepage, I can access it only over the view by jquery/js

Comment: Oh that's interesting. So the React component is listening to an event and updates the internal state. Can you find out what event it is listening to?

Comment: yeaa I think so, it's an input field an when you input something everything is fine, but when you emulate that input with .val() or text() it doesn't work. I'm still searching on which event it is listening to.

Comment: Try entering in the console `getEventListeners("input[data-reactid='.0.2.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.0.3.0.3.0.0']")`

Comment: when I use getEventListeners, I get Uncaught ReferenceError: getEventListeners is not defined, but give a look at this screenshot from google chrome dev tools: http://picpaste.de/b38127b47fbf42b4661e025fbbb8ee81.png
I tried also with .blur() but no way.