# jQuery: Update date input on Trello with function

Tags: jquery, trello

I'm trying to streamline some of the tasks I do several times a day on Trello, such as adding labels, dates and comments.  For some reason, when it comes to updating input fields my values update visually but when submitted they submit the default options.

I can't really fiddle what I've done, but as an example, this is what I've done to set the date.  This sets the value as per expectations, visually at least, but when I click the save button it saves it as the default day (tomorrow).

```
var d = new Date();
    month = d.getMonth() + 1,
    day = d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();
$('.js-dpicker-date-input').val(month +'/' + day + '/' + year);
```

[image]

> Press Save Button

[image]

> Saves Default (Tomorrow at 12PM)

I *think* this is because I've not actually typed anything into the input fields, but I don't know the solution.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: try $('.js-dpicker-date-input').val(month +'/' + day + '/' + year).trigger('change');

Comment: @daremachine no luck :(

Comment: their calendar is not jquery based but react based. You need to call prop.change but I don't think its possible outside from component.

Comment: @daremachine is there a hacky way of achieving this?  It's only going to be an extension anyway so it doesn't have to be the cleanest code.  I've tried to trigger a keypress to input a space after my date as that works when entering the date manually to no avail.  I can't trigger blur, focus, change or click on the input either.

Comment: its not possible, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937379/react-js-change-input-value-with-javascript. I recommend to you use API https://developers.trello.com/get-started/intro